# how to load css apart from css folder in webroot in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am unable to load `css` in `cakephp`. my directory structure is this

```
          webroot/
                   -bootstrap/
                              -css/
                                   bootstrap.min.css
                              -js
                              -fonts
                    -dist/
                           -css/
                    -plugin/
                            -font-awesome
```

I am using `$this->Html->css();` which point to css directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
$this->Html->css('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Comment: You can also specify a path relative to the `css` folder like `../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Comment: its giving path "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" in source which is unavailable. i am running on localhost.   inside ci my directory stucture is this.   https://localhost/codeigniter_folder/cakephpfolder/webroot//bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I have tested it in cakephp 3.x and its working for me. Which version of cakephp are you using

Comment: its working after setting RewriteBase in .htaccess. i am using 3.x version. thanks @Aman Rawat